# Google disabled use of the Maps API for V3

Tags: google-maps

I am an amateur website developer but proficient in html and javascript. 
I have a handful of websites using the Google Maps API V2 with no problem. I tried to upgrade to V3. I got a new API key and used the sample html (based on Australia) provided by Google. All I got was the **'disabled'** message. 
If I remove the key completely it works! What am I doing wrong?!! ([www.gn45.com/gmap.html](http://www.gn45.com/gmap.html))

Comment: I'm pretty sure that parts of the code have changed too have you tried refactoring your code

Comment: www.gn45.com/gmap.html here i was able to see the map

Comment: Have you done everything to migrate? [`Upgrading Your Google Maps JavaScript Application To v3`](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3)

Answer (score 0):

This message appears, because there's a particular domain whitelist, that is configured for each business account. By default, you can always access google APIs with an API key from localhost, but any other domain should be specifically set within account management.

With the mobile application, your index.html is read from the filesystem and then passed to in App Browser. Therefore google rejects a request to the API with API key. You can temporarily remove API key from your request and access the API without any, this way you'll have a 50k request/month limit, which should be sufficient for development purposes.

I'm looking for a way to configure this myself, as soon as I find one, I'll provide an update.